# The paradox of i.i.d. data (at least for me)

Tags: sampling, conditional-probability, independence

As far as my aggregate (and scarce) knowledge on statistics permits, I understood that if $X_1, X_2,..., X_n$ are i.i.d. random variables, then as the term implies they are independent and identically distributed.

My concern here is the former property of i.i.d. samples, which reads:
$$p(X_{n}|X_{i_1},X_{i_2},...,X_{i_k}) = p(X_{n}),$$

for any collection of distinct $i_j$'s s.t. $1 \leq i_j < n$.

However one knows that the aggregate of independent samples of identical distributions provide information about the distribution structure, and as a result about $X_n$ in the above case, so indeed it should not be the case that:
$$p(X_{n}|X_{i_1},X_{i_2},...,X_{i_k}) = p(X_{n}).$$

I know that I am victim of fallacy but I don't know why. Please help me out on this one.

Comment: Do you know Bayes rule? Heard of classics. vs Bayesian statistics? Priors?

Comment: I don't follow the argument at the end of your question. Can you be more explicit?

Comment: @Glen_b what is it exactly that you don't follow? What do you mean by the end of it? I am trying to say with different logics both an equality and an inequality seems plausible which is a paradox.

Comment: There's no paradox here--merely a failure to apply the appropriate definitions.  You cannot claim to have a paradox when you ignore the meaning of the words you use! In this instance, comparing the definition of *independent* to that of *probability* will reveal the error.

Comment: @whuber, I assume you have noticed the explicit "(at least for me)" in the title of my question and also the fact that I ask for help to find the "fallacy" of my argument, which points at the fact that this is indeed not a real paradox.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I think you are confusing an **estimated model** of a distribution with a **random variable**. Let's rewrite the independence assumption as follows:
$$
P(X_n | \theta, X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \dots, X_{i_k}) = P(X_n | \theta) \tag{1}
$$
which says that **if you know the underlying distribution of $X_n$** (and, for example, can identify it by a set of parameters $\theta$) then the distribution does not change given that you have observed a few samples from it.

For example, think of $X_n$ as the random variable representing the outcome of the $n$-th toss of a coin. Knowing the probability of *head* and *tail* for the coin (which, btw, assume is encoded in $\theta$) is enough to know the distribution of $X_n$. In particular, the outcome of the previous tosses does not change the probability of *head* or *tail* for the $n$-th toss, and $(1)$ holds.

Note, however, that $P(\theta | X_n) \neq P(\theta | X_{i_1}, X_{i_2}, \dots, X_{i_k})$.

Comment: Thank you very much. Quite up to the point. Quite funny that I guessed such an answer a while ago but I forgot about it....So as far as I understand the fallacy goes with implicitly assuming "a model" which can parametrize the distribution of random variable. Did I get it right?

Comment: @Cupitor: I'm glad it was useful. Yes, conditioned on the model, the independent random variables do not affect each other. But, how likely a given distribution is to have generated a sequence of outcomes changes as you see more samples from the underlying (true) distribution (regardless of the independence assumption).

Answer (score 14):

If you take a Bayesian approach and treat parameters describing the distribution of $X$ as a random variable/vector, then the observations indeed are *not* independent, but they would be *conditionally independent* given knowledge of $\theta$ hence $P(X_n \mid X_{n-1}, \ldots X_1, \theta) = P(X_n \mid \theta)$ would hold.

In a classical statistical approach, $\theta$ is *not a random variable.* Calculations are done as if we know what $\theta$ is. In some sense, you're always conditioning on $\theta$ (even if you don't know the value).

When you wrote, "... provide information about the distribution structure, and as a result about $X_n$" you implicitly were adopting a Bayesian approach but not doing it precisely. You're writing a property of IID samples that a frequentist would write, but the corresponding statement in a Bayesian setup would involve conditioning on $\theta$.

#### Bayesian vs. Classical statisticians

Let $x_i$ be the result of flipping a lopsided, unfair coin. We don't know the probability the coin lands heads.

- To the classical statistician, the frequentist, $P(x_i = H)$ is some parameter, let's call it $\theta$. Observe that $\theta$ here is a scalar, like the number 1/3. We may not know what the number is, but it's some number! It is *not* random!
- To the Bayesian statistician, $\theta$ itself is a random variable! This is extremely different!

The key idea here is that the Bayesian statistician extends the tools of probability to situations where the classical statistician *doesn't*. To the frequentist, $\theta$ isn't a random variable because *it only has one possible value*! Multiple outcomes are not possible! In the Bayesian's imagination though, multiple values of $\theta$ are possible, and the Bayesian is willing to model that uncertainty (in his own mind) using the tools of probability.

#### Where is this going?

Let's say we flip the coin $n$ times. One flip does not affect the outcome of the other. The classical statistician would call these independent flips (and indeed they are). We'll have:
$$P(x_n=H \mid x_{n-1}, x_{n-2}, \ldots,x_{1}) = P(x_n=H) = \theta $$
Where $\theta$ is some unknown parameter. (Remember, we don't know what it is, but it's *not* a random variable! It's some number.)

A Bayesian deep into subjective probability would say that what matters is the probability *from her perspective!*. If she sees 10 heads in a row, an 11th head is more likely because 10 heads in a row leads one to believe the coin is lopsided in favor of heads.

$$P(x_{11} = H \mid x_{10}=H, x_{9}=H, \ldots,x_{1}=H) > P(x_1 = H)$$

What has happened here? What is different?! Updating beliefs about a latent random variable $\theta$! If $\theta$ is treated as a random variable, the flips aren't independent anymore. But, the flips *are conditionally independent* given the value of $\theta$.

$$P(x_{11} = H \mid x_{10}=H, x_{9}=H, \ldots,x_{1}=H, \theta) = P(x_1 = H \mid \theta) = \theta $$

Conditioning on $\theta$ in a sense connects how the Bayesian and the classical statistician models the problem. Or to put it another way, the frequentist and the Bayesian statistician will agree *if the Bayesian conditions on $\theta$.*

#### Further notes

I've tried my best to give a short intro here, but what I've done is at best quite superficial and the concepts are in some sense quite deep. If you want to take a dive into the philosophy of probability, Savage's 1954 book, [Foundation of Statistics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0486623491) is a classic. Google for bayesian vs. frequentist and a ton of stuff will come up.

Another way to think about IID draws is [de Finetti's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Finetti%27s_theorem) and the notion of [exchangeability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exchangeable_random_variables). In a Bayesian framework, exchangeability is equivalent to independence conditional on some latent random variable (in this case, the lopsidedness of the coin).

Comment: In essence, the bayesian approach would treat a statement "i.i.d. random variables" not as an axiom that they *must* be IID but just as a very strong prior assumption that they are so - and if even stronger evidence suggests that it's extremely unlikely that the given assumptions are true, then this "disbelief in the given conditions" will be reflected in the results.

Comment: Thank you very much for your thorough answer. I have upvoted it, but I think Sobi's answer, points out more explicitly where the problem lies, i.e. implicitly assuming the model structure (or this is as far as I understood it)

Comment: @Matthew Gunn: neat, thorough, and very well explained! I learned a few things from your answer, thanks!